# what is the minimum number of points in affine plane.

Tags: geometry

what is minimum number of points in affine plane,

By the way: Here are the $\textbf{Three Axioms}$ for affine plane.

1. Given two distinct points $\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{Q}$, there is only one line  passing through them
2. Given a point $\textbf{P}$ and a line $\textit{l}$, if $\textbf{P}\not\in\textit{l}$,
   there is only one line passing through point $\textbf{P}$ and parallel to line $\textit{l}$
3. There exist three points $\textbf{P}$, $\textbf{Q}$, $\textbf{R}$ non-collinear

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have three points and three lines pass through the three points so far.

Comment: But three points do not form an affine plane because 1 tells you it has to be a triangle, but 2 tells you the triangle doesn't work. What about four points?

Comment: yep, four points and six lines, thx

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $K$ is any field, the vector space $V=K^2$ has always the structure of affine plane.

Now take for $K$ the smallest field you know.

Comment: "If K is any field, the vector space V=K2 has always the structure of affine plane" any idea how to prove that?

Comment: well, the smallest field is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Comment: @bsdshell: Define the lines to be the translates of the $1$-dimensional subspaces. Check the axioms!